# How to decompile or read a Lua File with LuaJIT Bytecode?

Tags: text, lua, decompiler, luajit

I want to decompile a Lua File that is compiled in LuaJIT Bytecode.

I have a Source Code of a Game but it's decompiled in LuaJIT Bytecode so it cannot be read by a normal Text Editor. (Also to mention that there is a official Link where you could download the Source Code but it has a 403 Forbidden error)

Is there a Method to read LuaJIT Bytecode with an specific Text Editor or decompile it?

here is a [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o3d8JZuxJimK8ME9ofuDLb1iSHz35irq/view?usp=sharing) I want to decompile/read if possible.

Feel free to download it and check it yourself.

Comment: Its not valid 2.1.0 bytecode and unluac also fails. Do you know the exact version? I would also try to contact the original author.

Comment: I contacted the developer with the issue that we cannot download the source code from the official Wiki of the Game. But I got no answer while I write this comment.

For the Lua Version I don't know which version is it using. I don't know how to check it.

Comment: Maybe it helps solving it:
The lua file was compiled with love2D Engine.

Comment: Hmm that makes it a bit more complicated, Love uses a slightly modified LuaJIT iirc. What love version? The newest one apparently is too new.

Comment: Wait a minute.

In the official Wiki of the Game for Modding it links a documentation of Lua 5.2.

I think the lua files are on v5.2.

Comment: Oh here is the [Wiki](http://gamedevstudiogame.com/).

Comment: LÖVE & LuaJIT - LuaJIT uses (currently) a modified Lua 5.1 - Version of LuaJIT: ```love.graphics.print(jit.version, 10, 10)``` - Version of Lua: ```love.graphics.print(_VERSION, 10, 10)```

Comment: I found an unofficial source: https://steamcommunity.com/app/773580/discussions/1/4328520278453816707/

Comment: @Luke100000 This a Post from me, yeah there is an unofficial Source but that doesn't include everything of the Source Code and it's outdated (Source Code created at the time where Game Dev Studio Version was 1.0.5.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously you could've used [LJD](https://github.com/Aussiemon/ljd), but now I'd use its replacement [LuaJIT Decompiler v2](https://github.com/marsinator358/luajit-decompiler-v2). Your file is valid LuaJIT 2.1b3 bytecode, and the decompiled text can be found [here](https://github.com/Aussiemon/Game-Dev-Studio-Source-Code/blob/main/game/game/theme.lua).

If you want to decompile the rest of the sources, just open LuaJIT Decompiler v2 and drop the folder of compiled files on the command window.

Alternatively you could run it through Powershell with something like:

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath $decompiler_path -ArgumentList "`"$sources_directory`" -e lua -s" -Wait
```